# Accessing an object's hash key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

I am using the Rails console. I have the following object: payment:

```
=> #<Invoice id: "14848", from: "Acme Processing", to_id: "Jones Electric", total: "$68.77", paid_at: "2017-01-19">
```

I can access to_id, by doing:

```
payment.to_id
```

and total:

```
payment.total
```

How do I get the value for Invoice id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access the values using payment[:to_id] and payment[:total] . Get more information about ruby Hashes [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html).

Comment: Yes, of course. I was confused about the way it was displayed in the console

Answer (score 0):

Seems invoice has relationship with payment, just do

```
payment.invoice.id
```